# Can firefox's multi-account containers extension be replicated in chrome or chromium based browsers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-extension, brave, brave-browser

I love the firefox extension multi-account containers. I want to switch to brave browser but I can't find a good alternative. Is it a functionality that can only work in firefox due to API limitations or is it possible to implement it in chromium based browsers via an extension?

If I want to create this extension can I make it exactly the same as firefox's multi-account containers? I tried to load the extension into brave but it has many errors due to the differences in the APIs I think. So the only way to do this would be to program it for chromium. Is that possible?

I found this reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/brave_browser/comments/kw2cff/brave_alternative_to_firefoxs_multiaccount/ it appears to suggest that containers are firefox exclusive and sessionbox is an alternative suggested. I tried sessionbox though it appears to be limited to having to click on the extension and then select a session to start the website in while multi-account containers can do that automatically if you set it to always open in container.

Are there extension API features that such an extension makes use of and chromium based browsers don't have?

Maybe this feature can be implemented not through an extension but directly through the browser, as brave is open source it should be possible for me to add this feature or fork it and add it there.

*[this question is a duplicate of another question I asked; an attempt to make it more clear; I removed the other question]*

Comment: Consider using the Edit function on your original question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Multi-account containers functionality requires [Contextual identities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextualIdentities) browser extension API and which is [only supported in FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextualIdentities#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

As for 2023, it's not possible to implement FF's multi-containers in Brave/Chrome.

But you can spread the word and vote for this feature here:
https://community.brave.com/t/equivalent-of-multi-account-containers-or-temporary-containers-extension-ff/135573

It's not a lost cause but this feature has been discussed by Brave's team since their launch, about 5 years ago:
https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/34

Their conclusion is that is too much work. They say this feature has to be implemented by Chrome first, otherwise they have to patch too many things.

The problem is that Google won't ever implement something like that in Chrome, IMO. The whole idea goes against their core business: track users for targeted advertisement.

There are some plugins you can give a try, but they are not practical (in my opinion). Also, I wouldn't trust a plugin to access all my browser data (history, cookies, etc).